# Unable to find proto buffer class in spark

Tags: apache-spark, buffer, protocols

I am learnning spark recently and I met one issue about the potocol buffers, I ran the below code in spark and got the "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to find proto buffer class".

```
object BasicSaveProtoBuf {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val master = args(0)
    val outputFile = args(1)
    val sc = new SparkContext(master, "BasicSaveProtoBuf", System.getenv("SPARK_HOME"))
    val conf = new Configuration()
    LzoProtobufBlockOutputFormat.setClassConf(classOf[Places.Venue], conf);
    val dnaLounge = Places.Venue.newBuilder()
    dnaLounge.setId(1);
    dnaLounge.setName("DNA Lounge")
    dnaLounge.setType(Places.Venue.VenueType.CLUB)
    val data = sc.parallelize(List(dnaLounge.build()))
    val outputData = data.map{ pb =>
      val protoWritable = ProtobufWritable.newInstance(classOf[Places.Venue]);
      protoWritable.set(pb)
      (null, protoWritable)
    }
    outputData.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(outputFile, classOf[Text], classOf[ProtobufWritable[Places.Venue]],
      classOf[LzoProtobufBlockOutputFormat[ProtobufWritable[Places.Venue]]], conf)
  }
}
```

And the places.proto is

```
message Venue {
    required int32 id = 1;
    required string name = 2;
    required VenueType type = 3;
    optional string address = 4;

enum VenueType {
    COFFEESHOP = 0;
    WORKPLACE = 1;
    CLUB = 2;
    OMNOMNOM = 3;
    OTHER = 4;
}
}
```

The exception log is:

```
16/11/30 09:34:27 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
java.io.IOException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to find proto buffer class
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1141)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.ParallelCollectionPartition.readObject(ParallelCollectionRDD.scala:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1893)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:185)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to find proto buffer class
    at com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite$SerializedForm.readResolve(GeneratedMessageLite.java:775)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadResolve(ObjectStreamClass.java:1104)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1807)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1706)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1344)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:500)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.ParallelCollectionPartition$$anonfun$readObject$1.apply$mcV$sp(ParallelCollectionRDD.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1138)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.oreilly.learningsparkexamples.proto.Places$Venue
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:191)
    at com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite$SerializedForm.readResolve(GeneratedMessageLite.java:768)
    ... 37 more
```

As I check the protocol buffers class Places.Venue is really in the jar built by the class.Has anybody met this issue before? Any help is appreciated!
Nobody knows this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of time search, finally I solve it by adding

```
spark.serializer  org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer
```

in the spark-defaults.conf file

Answer (score 0):

Your exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.oreilly.learningsparkexamples.proto.Places$Venue
```

states that class

```
com.oreilly.learningsparkexamples.proto.Places$Venue
```

is not found in your classpath.

You can add a jar with this class to `spark.executor.extraClassPath` option to spark-defaults.conf so it would be distributed to each executor as you are accessing it in rdd.map function (which is executed in executor process):

```
val outputData = data.map{ pb =>
  val protoWritable = ProtobufWritable.newInstance(classOf[Places.Venue]);
  protoWritable.set(pb)
  (null, protoWritable)
}
```

All Spark properties and default values are here: [Spark Configuration](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html)

Comment: As I said, the class is in the target jar which generated by my project and also I tried your method, but it did not work.